# Show Form on applications main window

Tags: c#, winforms

Two windows apps communicate through .net remoting.  The host publishes an instance of a class that the client can call methods on through remoting.

The class has a method which pops up a form if not already visible, using form.Show() and performs some functions in a thread.

When the thread completes the form disappears even though I don't explicitely close it. The instance of the class does not go out of scope, and the class instance maintains a reference to the form.

I don't want the form to disappear and am thinking that if I use the Form.Show(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window) overload this would work if I pass the applcation main form to the Show method.  The problem is my class instance knows nothing about the application.  Is there any way to find the applications main form?

The form is being created and shown inside the thread.

Comment: Are you creating the form inside the thread? Are are you creating the form and Showing it then using a thread to perform other functions. I don't see how specifying an owner window when change anything (it just prevents the owner from appearing on-top of new form IIRC).

Comment: I have a function which takes the name of a method to call, the fuction spins up a thread and executes the function in the thread.  The solution is essentially a dynamic scripting system, so the function that starts the thread has no idea what it's actually executing, and the function that's being run inside the thread doesn't know anything about the calling function or application.

Comment: @Grant Winny - I'll have to build a simplified example.  Will take some time... stay tuned